# Как можно добавить лейбл у кнопки по аналогии с селектом (Material ui)

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, ui, material-ui

Всем привет.
Используется библиотека Material UI
Как можно добавить для кнопки лейбл. Возможно есть какие-то костыли?

[image: example]

Comment: Да, костыли есть, их полно: смотри документацию и/или исходники использумой библиотеки (ну или любого другого UI-набора в стиле material design). Общий принцип реализации, если интересно - в абсолютном позиционировании внутри относительного (в общей обертке для инпута и лейбла), ну и транзишн на трансформ label (обычно это делается на чистом CSS).

Comment: Костыли придется делать, при нажатии на кнопку, т.к. бордер делается обычным css border, а пустое место между Lable и border добавляется простым белым фоном у лейбла. Если кнопка при нажатии никак внешне не изменяется, то все будет окей, если меняется фон, то получится фигня, но можно при нажатии просто скрывать лейбл. См пример ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все отступы на глаз подбирал.
Можно добавить анимации смещения лейбла при нажатии, чтобы выглядело более презентабельно.

```css
.btn {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .5rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn:active {
  background: gray;
}

.btn2:active > .btn__label {
  display: none;
}

.btn__name {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.btn__label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  top: -0.5rem;
}

.btn3__label {
  background: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
  
}



/*длины на глаз подогнал*/
.btn3::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width:  3rem;
  height: 1px;
  top: -1px;
  left: .5rem;
  background: white;
}

.btn3:active::before {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn1">
  <div class="btn__label">label</div>
  <div class="btn__name">Лейбл с фоном</div>
</button>

<br/>

<button class="btn btn2">
  <div class="btn__label">label</div>
  <div class="btn__name">Скрываем лейбл с фоном</div>
</button>

<br/>


<button class="btn btn3">
  <div class="btn__label btn3__label">label</div>
  <div class="btn__name">Лейбл без фона</div>
</button>
```